# unable to apply StringIndexer method on dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have created dataframe named **df** from CSV file. Dataframe is

```
+---+---+---+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
|X  |Y  |Z  |class   |source                                           |
+---+---+---+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
|33 |36 |51 |Eat_meat|Accelerometer-2011-03-24-13-21-39-eat_meat-f1.txt|
|33 |36 |51 |Eat_meat|Accelerometer-2011-03-24-13-21-39-eat_meat-f1.txt|
|33 |35 |53 |Eat_meat|Accelerometer-2011-03-24-13-21-39-eat_meat-f1.txt|
|31 |37 |52 |Eat_meat|Accelerometer-2011-03-24-13-21-39-eat_meat-f1.txt|
|32 |36 |52 |Eat_meat|Accelerometer-2011-03-24-13-21-39-eat_meat-f1.txt|
|32 |36 |51 |Eat_meat|Accelerometer-2011-03-24-13-21-39-eat_meat-f1.txt|
|32 |36 |51 |Eat_meat|Accelerometer-2011-03-24-13-21-39-eat_meat-f1.txt|
|33 |36 |53 |Eat_meat|Accelerometer-2011-03-24-13-21-39-eat_meat-f1.txt|
|33 |35 |52 |Eat_meat|Accelerometer-2011-03-24-13-21-39-eat_meat-f1.txt|
|33 |36 |52 |Eat_meat|Accelerometer-2011-03-24-13-21-39-eat_meat-f1.txt|
+---+---+---+--------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to apply **StringIndexer** to convert the column named **class** to indices. I tried following code.

```
val indexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("X")
  .setOutputCol("classIndex")

val indexed = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
indexed.show()
```

This code throws following error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction.asNondeterministic()Lorg/apache/spark/sql/expressions/UserDefinedFunction;
>       at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexerModel.transform

This error occurs when I try yo apply transform function. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Hopefully you are using spark 2.4

Comment: @Rakshith yes . Spark version 2.4.0 and Scala version 2.11.8

Answer (score 0):

That problem can appear due to version mismatches.
Check if the answer in this question helps.

[Apache Spark: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError .rddToPairRDDFunctions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388450/apache-spark-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-rddtopairrddfunctions)